# arrayWithObjects: Objects should be NSStrings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I used this code to file the rows in my UIPickerView:

```
self.component1Data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Sample", @"Sample1", @"...", nil];
```

How can I get a NSString instead of the "sample"? I tried it with "%@" but it doesn't work:

```
self.component1Data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"%@",string, @"%@",string2, @"...", nil];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
self.component1Data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: string, string2, nil];
```

Assuming string and string2 are of type `NSString *`.

Comment: Haha, great :)
It is to late.